# TSQL: How do I do a self-join in XML to get a nested document?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlxml, for-xml

I have a SQL Server 2005 table like this:

```
create table Taxonomy(
CategoryId integer primary key,
ParentCategoryId integer references Taxonomy(CategoryId),
CategoryDescription varchar(50) 
)
```

with data looking like

`CategoryIdParentCategoryIdCategoryDescription
123nullfoo345123bar`

I'd like to query it into an xml document like this:

```
<taxonomy>
<category categoryid="123" categorydescription="foo">
      <category id="455" categorydescription="bar"/>
</category>
</taxonomy>
```

Is it possible to do this with FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS? Or do I need to use FOR XML EXPLICIT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible but the main limitation is that the levels of the hierarchy must be hard coded. The SQL Server Books Online has a description of how to represent hierarchies in XML at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345137(SQL.90).aspx#forxml2k5_topic5). Below is a sample query that produces the XML you requested:

```
SELECT [CategoryId] as "@CategoryID"
      ,[CategoryDescription] as "@CategoryDescription"
      ,(SELECT [CategoryId]
       ,[CategoryDescription]
       FROM [dbo].[Taxonomy] "Category"
       WHERE ParentCategoryId = rootQuery.CategoryId
       FOR XML AUTO, TYPE)
FROM [dbo].[Taxonomy] as rootQuery
where [ParentCategoryId] is null
FOR XML PATH('Category'), ROOT('Taxonomy')
```